# How to insert the name of the Axiom next to Axiom

Tags: theorems

```
\begin{axiom} (blah)   
\end{axiom}
```

gives "Axiom 1". How can I make this so that I have "Axiom 1 (blah)." instead? Tags are probably not correct. I just got started with Latex today.

Comment: Assuming that `axiom` is some kind of theorem, we would need to see a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that highlights the problem. Why? Because there are many ways in which one can define `axiom`, and a MWE would help highlight that.

Comment: I just want the name of the axiom next to axiom instead of it being to the right side of the period.

Comment: Yes, and I (we) just want to see your minimal example, instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Assuming you defined `axiom` using something like `\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}`, then it's enough to use the optional argument: `\begin{axiom}[Axiom of extensionality]
test
\end{axiom}`.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newcounter{x}\setcounter{x}{1}
\newtheorem{inneraxiom}{Axiom}
\newenvironment{axiom}[1]
  {\renewcommand\theinneraxiom{\arabic{x} (#1)}\inneraxiom\stepcounter{x}}
  {\endinneraxiom}

\begin{document}

\begin{axiom}{blah}
....
\end{axiom}

\end{document}
```